# how to set scrollbar in jpanel at the end when new component added

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a `JPanel`(A) with `BoxLayout`, and it is embed in another `JPanel`(B) with `JScrollPane`.
I want to set the position of scroll at the bottom when a new component is added to A. 
I try the code below, but it prevent to use scroll up to see all A context:(scroll is fixed at the bottom!)

```
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
        e.getAdjustable().setValue(e.getAdjustable().getMaximum());  
    }
});
```

Does any one have another solution?

Comment: The reason that it gets fixed at the bottom is because you have an adjustmentListener which puts the scrollbar to the bottom everytime you try to move it! You don't want to have this listener you only need to set the value to the maximum after adding the component (at a certain point of the code), not as part of an event-driven system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this after you add a new componenet:

```
JScrollBar sb = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
sb.setValue( sb.getMaximum() );//not sb.getMaximumValue()
```

**Edit:**

You can use this instead of the upper code.

```
panel.revalidate();
int height = (int)panel.getPreferredSize().getHeight();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,height,10,10);
panel.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
```

Comment: When you add components for a panel try invoking `revalidate()` on the panel to make sure the components are layed out properly. Maybe it will work this way.

Comment: I use it, but it did not go exactly at the end : panel.add(textarea);
  vScrollBar.setValue( vScrollBar.getMaximum());
  panel.revalidate();

Comment: Can you try the other code that i just edited. I hope it would do the trick.